# Laravel - textarea con varias lineas - Query Builder

Tags: laravel, sql, insert, textarea

tengo una duda y no sé como resolverla...
Estoy con mi primer proyecto en Laravel y cuando hago un insert con el query builder de un campo que era un textarea multilínea, me quita todos los saltos de línea.

¿Cómo hago para que lo mantenga?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Si intentas imprimir con un `echo` el texto antes de almacenarlo, qué te aparece?

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que el problema no es el query builder, si no el helper para imprimir el dato en la vista. Lo que he hecho es usar un echo nl2br() y ya salen los saltos de línea en la vista. Pero claro, no sé si hay algo en laravel para imprimir con la doble llave